# Replace duplicate rows by one column

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file in the below format.

[[image: .[1]]

I tried using awk and sed in all the possible ways which i am aware of but couldn't find a way to reformat the file in the format which i am looking for. I would like to have the file in the below format.

[image]

Any suggestions/help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Darshan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with an input like this --

```
Physical Disk : 'IBM (67)
device=/dev/mapper/1234
shareddisk=true
Physical Disk : 'IBM (68)
device=/dev/mapper/6789
shareddisk=true
```

the following awk script outputs --

```
awk -v RS="" 'BEGIN{print "Phys disk  Device                 shareddisk"} {j=0; for (i=0; i<3; i++) {print substr($(4+j),2) ,$(5+j), $(6+j), $(7+j); j+=7} }' input

Phys disk  Device                  shareddisk
IBM (67) device=/dev/mapper/1234 shareddisk=true
IBM (68) device=/dev/mapper/6789 shareddisk=true
```